# How to read last word in text file using powershell(1.0)?

Tags: windows, powershell

I've a text file content like below,

---

```
     123    123   123   123   123   Exchange
```

---

i want that last word "*Exchange*", need solution in powershell. please help me.

Note: beginning of the file is TAB, also between the Character.

Thanks,
RaM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the line, remove empty entries if exist, and get the last element:

```
$content= Get-Content file.txt
$content.Split("`t",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Shay your content exactly suites for my script.

Answer (score 2):

This Function will take a text file path and return the last word of a last line of text file. It will ignore any blank line that may be in the text file.

```
Function Get-Last-Word($path){ 
    $file = (Get-Content $path | Measure-Object)
    $numberOfLines = $file.Count
    $numberOfWords = (Get-Content $path | Select -Index ($numberOfLines -1) | Measure-Object -word)
    $Line = Get-Content $path | Select -Index ($numberOfLines -1)
    $wordArray = $Line.Split("`t")
    $wordArray[($numberOfWords.Words - 1)]
}
```

Example:
`Get-Last-Word "C:\Myfolder\MyTextfile.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

How about this one-liner:

```
[Regex]::Match((Get-Content .\file_name.txt) -Join ' ', '(\w+)[^\w]*$').Groups[1].Value
```

Not sure if you have -Join available on Powershell v1, if so then this:

```
$t = '';Get-Content .\file_name.txt | % {$t += " $_"};[Regex]::Match($t, '(\w+)[^\w]*$').Groups[1].Value
```