# PS1 Replace or Remove a single character without rewriting the whole file

Tags: powershell

**Is it possible to remove or replace the last character on the last non-whitespace line of a file using PowerShell 1?**

**I'm trying to get an Uptime log that is precise to within 5 minutes.**

I've found that there are built logs and commands that can be accessed through command prompt that would tell me when the last time a computer was booted up, or when it shut down correctly, but the native uptime log only records once every 24 hrs, so if there is a power failure, I won't know how long the system has been offline with any precision more refined than 24 hours.

So I have created the following script:

```
$bootTime = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
$formBootTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($bootTime)
$uptime = (Get-Date)-$formBootTime
"$formBootTime,$(Get-Date),{0:00},{1:00},{2:00},{3:00}" -f $uptime.Days,$uptime.Hours,$uptime.Minutes,$uptime.Seconds >> C:\UptimeTracker.csv
```

However, this gets tediously long to scroll through when I want to evaluate how long my machine has been running over the last X days.

So I thought I would add a marker to identify the current or most recent Uptime log per any given Boot.

**But in order for that to work I would need to be able to remove said marker as soon as the previous record is no longer the relevant record.**

```
$bootTime = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
$formBootTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($bootTime)
$file = (Get-Content c:\UptimeTracker.csv | Measure-Object)
$numberOfLines = $file.Count
$numberOfWords = (Get-Content c:\UptimeTracker.csv | Select -Index ($numberOfLines -1) | Measure-Object -word)
$Line = Get-Content c:\UptimeTracker.csv | Select -Index ($numberOfLines -2)
$wordArray = $Line.Split(",")
$LastLineBT = $wordArray[0]
if($LastLineBT -eq $formBootTime) {
    $unmark = "true"
}
else
{$unmark = "false"}

if($unmark == "true"){ <remove last character of file> }

$uptime = (Get-Date)-$formBootTime 
"$formBootTime,$(Get-Date),{0:00},{1:00},{2:00},{3:00},X" -f $uptime.Days,$uptime.Hours,$uptime.Minutes, $uptime.Seconds >> C:\UptimeTracker.csv
```

Some of the above is borrowed and modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16210970/11035837

I have seen several methods that receive the file as the input file and write to a different output file, and from there it would be an easy thing to do to script renaming the new and old files to switch their positions (new, old, standby - and rotate) the reason I'm trying not to rewrite the whole file is to reduce those instances where the command/script is interrupted and the action doesn't complete.  Ideally the only time the action doesn't complete would be on a power failure. However, I have already seen in a previous version, it would skip 5 minute intervals occasionally for up to 15 minutes without any change in the last reported boot time.  **I suspect this has to do with other higher priority processes preventing the task scheduler from running the script.**  If this is the case, then a complete rewrite of the file failing part way through the script would lose some percentage of the existing log data, and **I would rather miss the latest record than all the data.**

**Nothing I have found indicates any ability to remove/replace the last character (or two since one is a newline char), neither have I found anything that explicitly declares this is not possible - I have found declarations that it is not possible to elective replace inner or beginning content without a complete rewrite.**

Barring any solution definitive answer, or if the definitive answer is no this cannot be done, then I will attempt something like the following:

```
if($unmark == "true"){     
    $input = "C:\UptimeTracker_CUR.csv"
    $output = "C:\UptimeTracker_NEW.csv"

    $content = Get-Content $input
    $content[-2] = $content[-2] -replace 'X', ' '
    $content | Set-Content $output
    Rename-Item -Path "C:\UptimeTracker_CUR.csv" -NewName "C:\UptimeTracker_SBY.csv"
    Rename-Item -Path "C:\UptimeTracker_NEW.csv" -NewName "C:\UptimeTracker_CUR.csv"
}
```

**EDIT - due to multi-read comment by TheMadTechnician**

```
...
$file = Get-Content c:\UptimeTracker.csv
$fileMeasure = ($file | Measure-Object)
$numberOfLines = $fileMeasure.Count
$numberOfWords = ($file | Select -Index ($numberOfLines -1) | Measure-Object -word)
$Line = $file | Select -Index ($numberOfLines -2)
...
...
if($unmark == "true"){     
    $output = "C:\UptimeTracker_NEW.csv"

    $file[-2] = $file[-2] -replace 'X', ' '
    $file | Set-Content $output
    Rename-Item -Path "C:\UptimeTracker.csv" -NewName "C:\UptimeTracker_SBY.csv"
    Rename-Item -Path "C:\UptimeTracker_NEW.csv" -NewName "C:\UptimeTracker.csv"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the whole file in several times, which has got to be slowing the whole script down. I would suggest reading the whole file in, determining if you need to clear your flag, then do so when you output, adding your new line to the file. Assuming you aren't still running PowerShell v2, you can do this:

```
$bootTime = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
$formBootTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($bootTime)
$uptime = (Get-Date)-$formBootTime
$File = Get-Content c:\UptimeTracker.csv -raw
if($File.trim().split("`n")[-1].Split(',')[0] -eq $formBootTime){
    $File.trim() -replace 'X(?=\s*$)',' '
}else{
    $File.Trim()
},("$formBootTime,$(Get-Date),{0:00},{1:00},{2:00},{3:00},X" -f $uptime.Days,$uptime.Hours,$uptime.Minutes, $uptime.Seconds)|Set-Content c:\UptimeTracker.csv
```

If you are running an old version you will not have the `-raw` option for `Get-Content`. As a work around you can do this instead, and the same solution should still work.

```
$bootTime = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
$formBootTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($bootTime)
$uptime = (Get-Date)-$formBootTime
$File = (Get-Content c:\UptimeTracker.csv) -Join "`n"
if($File.trim().split("`n")[-1].Split(',')[0] -eq $formBootTime){
    $File.trim() -replace 'X(?=\s*$)',' '
}else{
    $File.Trim()
},("$formBootTime,$(Get-Date),{0:00},{1:00},{2:00},{3:00},X" -f $uptime.Days,$uptime.Hours,$uptime.Minutes, $uptime.Seconds)|Set-Content c:\UptimeTracker.csv
```

This is going to be slower, so should be considered a secondary option since you'll have to read the whole file in as an array of strings, and convert it to a single multi-line string.

Comment: I'm not "still running PowerShell v2" ... I'm still running v1
---I have several standalone machines that have no network access that I need to implement a solution for that doesn't require additional installations as that would require certain bureaucratic work that would significantly delay progress.  Though I am considering having advanced versions of PowerShell installed later anyway so this is easier when additional scripting may be required.

Comment: I've added an alternative for older versions of PowerShell.